# How to set debugger up?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am writing an add in for an application. To call methods i import the jar and then call the methods available, To export i export my application as a runnable jar to the extensions folder of the application im producing this for and then run that application.

However, how can i debug this? I have no idea and at the moment am having to resort to using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), exceptionMessage or something)` . This is tedious and really not user friendly. Can anyone help me, i am using eclipse to develop.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Project properties and select "Java Build Path"
- In the "Source" tab, click "Link Source"
- Link the relevant source files to your project, repeating for multiple sources
- Navigate to the class you want to debug and set a breakpoint where you desire
- Launch the application in debug mode.

That should do it.